# How can I listen UIApplication lifecycle iOS in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to detect my iOS app write with flutter move to background and going on foreground. Im used to **WidgetsBindingObserver** to listen lifecycle in flutter. But it don't work exactly not my expectation. When I push native controller in flutter app lifecycle trigger **AppLifecycleState.paused** but my app is running. Anyone have just faced this problem? and the way that you address issue. Thanks

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if(state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      _viewModel.applicationMoveToBackground();

    } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      _viewModel.applicationMoveToForeground();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

I addressed this issue by workaround with FlutterBasicMessageChannel to emit iOS **UIApplication** lifecycle to flutter.
In iOS Runner App:

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

    var applicationLifeCycleChannel: FlutterBasicMessageChannel!

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

        applicationLifeCycleChannel = FlutterBasicMessageChannel(
            name: "applicationLifeCycle",
            binaryMessenger: (window.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController).binaryMessenger,
            codec: FlutterStringCodec.sharedInstance())
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    override func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        applicationLifeCycleChannel.sendMessage("applicationWillTerminate")
    }

    override func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        applicationLifeCycleChannel.sendMessage("applicationWillEnterForeground")
    }

    override func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        applicationLifeCycleChannel.sendMessage("applicationDidEnterBackground")
    }
}
```

In Flutter App:

```dart
 static const applicationLifecycleChannel = BasicMessageChannel<String>('applicationLifeCycle', StringCodec());
static const kApplicationWillTerminate = 'applicationWillTerminate';
  static const kApplicationWillEnterForeground = 'applicationWillEnterForeground';
  static const kApplicationDidEnterBackground = 'applicationDidEnterBackground';

  @override
  void initState() {
    applicationLifecycleChannel.setMessageHandler((message) async {
      switch(message) {
        case kApplicationWillTerminate:
          break;
        case kApplicationWillEnterForeground:
          _viewModel.applicationMoveToForeground();
          break;
        case kApplicationDidEnterBackground:
          _viewModel.applicationMoveToBackground();
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      return message;
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using WidgetsBindingObserver?

```
class _PageState extends State<Page> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    }

    @override
    dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    }

    @override
    void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
        super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
        if(state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
          _viewModel.applicationMoveToBackground();

        } else if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
          _viewModel.applicationMoveToForeground();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, i used to above code in my project, but i don't want application move to pause state when i push new native controller from flutter such as Image Picker.