# How to make app sleep on iOS flutter when I open other apps?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

How can I make the app call initState on iOS every time I re open the app? On Android the app kind of sleeps and once it opens from outside the app it executes the function in initState, but with iOS when I reopen the app it shows same previous state without executing initState

Comment: In general it is considered desirable on ios that apps are in the same state in which you left them.  You can listen to `willEnterForeground` if you want to take some action when the app becomes active https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065632/how-can-i-listen-uiapplication-lifecycle-ios-in-flutter

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In IOS when you go to Home Screen your app goes to inactive state. And when you return to your app, your app will call `willEnterForeground` notification which you can listen to do everything you want

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623076-applicationwillenterforeground